# Vertical alignment of characters in a QTextEdid (or QPlainTextEdit)

Tags: qt4, qtextedit, qplaintextedit

I'm trying to write the following nice table in a QTextEdit/QPlainTextEdit:

```
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 2---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

But when I do `appendPlainText(QString)` I don't get characters aligned vertically.  It seems each character has a different width so the result is almost a mess, with text kind of left aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the font used to display the text in the widget is a [Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). If necessary, change the font to for example 'Courier New' using [QWidget::setFont()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#font-prop)